# Blank screen on boot (Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, sound

I dual boot Ubuntu Studio 22.04 and Windows 10 pro.

I rebooted into Windows to play a couple of steam games. When I tried to boot back into Linux, to do some work, I just got a blank screen instead of my desktop.

Pressing Ctrl-Alt-F1 didn't do anything. Same with Ctrl-Alt-F2, f3, f4, f7, etc. Only pressing the power button at this point shut the system successfully.

Tried rebooting a couple of times, but obviously the problem didn't go away. Before the blank screen, I hear the usual "bop! bop! bop!" sound in my speakers, which is what normally happens when USB soundcard comes online, just before login. Immediately after that point comes the problem.

FYI I can still boot into Windows.

I did some googling, which lead me to this guide:

[My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162087#162087)

It recommends I repair grub, which I did by booting the Ubuntu Studio live disk, and running Boot-Repair. That got me a new grub menu, but I still can't get into the desktop unfortunately. So it didn't solve the problem. It did demonstrate that I can still boot into an Ubuntu desktop though, just not the one I have installed on my internal SSD.

The SSD, by the way, is a 2tb Crucial MX500. It has a 1000Gb Windows partition, about a 300Gb Linux partition, and a heap of left over space I haven't allocated yet.

Comment: +1; If you wish, you can create an answer your own question and after a couple of days 'accept' it (click on the tick mark). That will make it easy for other users to see, that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! I tried booting up by selecting an earlier kernel in the grub menu. It booted fine! Then I discovered there were a whole swag of updates available with the word 'nvidia' in them. I installed the updates, and now it seems to run fine on the latest kernel (5.15.0-33-lowlatency).

Comment: Yes, doing a kernel update without also updating the nvidia driver can cause this - happened to me as well a few weeks ago.